# Python 2 file.writelines() Unicode gives different results on Windows and Linux

Tags: linux, windows, python-2.7

For the same code below:

```
import os

filename = "text.txt"
data = [
    [
    u"hello world1",
    u"hello world2",
    u"hello world3",
    ],
    [
    u"hello world1",
    u"hello world2",
    u"hello world3",
    ],
]

# remove file if exist
if os.path.isfile(filename): os.remove(filename)

with open(filename, "ab+") as f:
    for item in data:
        f.writelines(item)
        f.write("\n")
```

On Windows, the text.txt gives:
[image]

but on Linux:

[image]

Can some explain why and how can I get similar result as Linux on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

You should explicitly specify the encoding when use `file.writelines()`.

You can use `with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:` insteed of using `with open(filename, "ab+") as f:`

**Explanation :**

On Windows, the default encoding for file I/O is usually `cp1252`, which is a superset of `ASCII` that includes many common characters used in Western European languages. This means that if you write Unicode strings to a file on Windows using `file.writelines()`, they will be automatically encoded to `cp1252` before being written to the file.

On Linux, the default encoding for file I/O is usually `UTF-8`, which is a variable-length encoding that can represent any Unicode character. If you write Unicode strings to a file on Linux using `file.writelines()`, they will be encoded to `UTF-8` before being written to the file.

Comment: In Python 2, thee is no `encoding` argument for `open`

Comment: @chewinggum, In Python 2, the default encoding is ASCII.